# Partition date on a new timestamp to get previous timestamp

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a table which looks like:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | timestamp
----------------------------------------
  1  |  2   |  3   | 2020-1-16 16:11:10
----------------------------------------
  1  |  2   |  3   | 2020-1-16 16:13:20
----------------------------------------
  1  |  2   |  3   | 2020-1-24 09:29:24
```

I want to create another column which gives me the previous date but partitions it by day. Also if it has no previous date, then it should return the same date. It should look like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | timestamp          | prev_timestamp
------------------------------------------------------------
  1  |  2   |  3   | 2020-1-16 16:11:10 | 2020-1-16 16:11:10
------------------------------------------------------------
  1  |  2   |  3   | 2020-1-16 16:13:20 | 2020-1-16 16:11:10
-------------------------------------------------------------
  1  |  2   |  3   | 2020-1-24 9:29:24  | 2020-1-24 09:29:24
```

I know i can use `lag` and `partition by` but then for the timestamp `2020-1-24 9:29:24` it gives me a previous timestamp of `2020-1-16 16:13:20`  which i do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want just with `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(timestamp, 1, timestamp) over (partition by col1, col2, col3, date(timestamp)
                                          order by timestamp
                                         ) as prev_timestamp
from t;
```

No conditional logic or subquery is necessary.  You simply want to get the previous timestamp on the same day and `lag()` does that.

Comment: This works too! For Athena its just date(timestamp) though

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()` and conditional logic:

```
select 
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    case when date_trunc(prev_timestamp) = date_trunc(timestamp) 
        then prev_timestamp 
        else timestamp 
    end prev_timestamp
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lag(timestamp) over(partition by col1, col2, col3 order by timestamp) prev_timestamp
    from mytable t
) t
```

You can remove the nested query by repeating the `lag()` expression like so:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case when date_trunc(lag(timestamp) over(partition by col1, col2, col3 order by timestamp)) = date_trunc(timestamp) 
        then lag(timestamp) over(partition by col1, col2, col3 order by timestamp) 
        else timestamp 
    end prev_timestamp
from mytable t
```